# Worst case randomized algorithm

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I'm trying to figure out the probability of the worst case happening in this type of event.

I have k lines and k amount of people. To simulate putting someone in line, a random number between 0-k is chosen & a person is added to that line.

I understand the maximum line length in the worst case is k, if the same random number is chosen agan and again.

How can I go about finding the probability of this worst case happnening?

Thanks!

Comment: You have k-1 times that someone is put in the same line as the first one.  So the answer is $k^{k-1}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need all $k$ people to go into a single line. For any given line, each person has a $1/k$ chance, so the probability of all $k$ going into a given line is $(1/k)^k.$ Then there are $k$ different lines this could happen for so the probability that all $k$ people end up in the same line is $k(1/k)^k = (1/k)^{k-1}$